# 'checkout' a folder outside home directory in rabbitVCS

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I am using rabbitVCS in Ubuntu for version control.
I have a folder in home directory, and I can 'checkout' it without any problem.
For the second folder which is in another partition (a NTFS partition that is mounted), clicking on the 'checkout' gives me the following error:

Can't set permission on '...svn/svn-DklBkp' operation not permitted.

It seems that rabbitVCS needs a sudo access to be able to run 'checkout'. How can I give rabbitVCS the root access to be able to run 'checkout' on this folder?

Comment: did you try changing the permission of the folder?

Comment: Yes. That was the reason. I changed it and rabbitVCS no longer complains about permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The partition should be mounted with correct user access. To do this you should check the /etc/fstab and change the umask. [This link](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/38125-SVN-error-on-NTFS-partition-from-Linux) provides more information.
Alternatively you can use a program like 'NTFS configuration tools' and change the permission of partition with a click.